# Why does Linux C serial read only work with high CPU?

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I am reading from a serial port (in blocking mode) using the following code

```
    int fd;

    int res;
    res = open_port(O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY, &fd);


    while (num_bytes_read < C_BUFFER_ENTRY_SIZE)
    {
        num_buf_byte_remaining = C_BUFFER_ENTRY_SIZE - num_bytes_read;      
        rc = read(fd, &buf[num_bytes_read], num_buf_byte_remaining);

        if (rc > 0)
        {
            num_bytes_read += rc;
        }

        if (rc == -1)
        {
            printf("Read error %s\n",strerror(errno));
        }
    }
```

The port I am reding from is /dev/ttyUSB0 (a serial port) that is configured using the following configuration.

```
    // BAUDRATE B3000000
int open_port(int flags, int *fd)
{
    struct termios options;
    *fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", flags | O_NOCTTY);

    if(*fd < 0){
        printf("Error opening port\n");
        return 1;
    } else{
        printf("Port handle is %d\n", *fd);
    }

    options.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
    options.c_iflag = 0;
    options.c_oflag = 0;
    options.c_lflag = 0;
    options.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    options.c_cc[VMIN] = 200;
    tcflush(*fd, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(*fd, TCSANOW, &options);

    return 0;
}
```

The amount of data being transferred over this serial link is very high (approximately 1-2Mbps) and so the reads need to be quick.

The behaviour I am seeing is that the read loop misses data quite frequently when the system is running normally. However, when I increase the loading using `nice -n 20 cat /dev/zero > /dev/null` all of the errors suddenly stop (I have a header + count + CRCpacket structure so can check corruption and continuity).

1. Why would increasing the CPU loading actually make the performance of this loop better?
2. Do I need to change the terminal settings to improve the performance? (I have tried setting VMIN to 0)

EDIT

Based on the comments below I will expand upon the above. The `buf` variable that data is where the data read from the serial port is put. This while loop continues until buf has C_BUFFER_ENTRY_SIZE (4096) of bytes in it.

After the while loop breaks (because the num of bytes are equal to 4906) `buf` is added to a queue to be read from a second thread. The queue is protected by mutexes and conditional variables see below.

```
/// function is after above while 1 loop
add_to_queue(buf,num_bytes_read);

// ring buff struct
typedef struct
{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t fill;
    pthread_cond_t empty;
    int s_icm_idx; // InComing Message index
    int s_ogm_idx; // OutGoing Message index
    int s_entry_count;
    int s_entry_count_hi;
    int used_bytes[10000];
    ring_buffer_data_t buffer[10000];
}ring_buffer_t;

typedef struct
{
    char data[4096];
}ring_buffer_data_t;


///
int add_to_queue(void* a_data, int a_bytes)
{
    int ret_val = 0;

    if (a_bytes > C_BUFFER_ENTRY_SIZE)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&(circ_buf.mutex));

    while (circ_buf.s_entry_count == 10000) 
    {
        ret_val = 1;
        pthread_cond_wait(&(circ_buf.empty), &(circ_buf.mutex));
    }

    /* Put the data on the queue, set how many bytes of the queue */
    /* are used and then incoming message index and the queue     */
    /* entry counter.                                             */
    memcpy(&(circ_buf.buffer[circ_buf.s_icm_idx]), a_data, a_bytes);
    circ_buf.used_bytes[circ_buf.s_icm_idx] = a_bytes;

    circ_buf.s_icm_idx = (circ_buf.s_icm_idx + 1) % 10000;
    crc_buf.s_entry_count++;

    pthread_cond_signal(&(circ_buf.fill));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(circ_buf.mutex));

    return ret_val;
}
```

The second thread reads data from this queue then parses each 4906 byte segement using a simple state machine. I.e. loops through the bytes until a header bytes is found, then checks `idx +  5` to get CRC, performs CRC over the whole 6 bytes if the crc is valid then reads the message.

The corrupted data I am seeing read from the serial is indicated by the CRC failing. When I load the CPU the CRC check does not fail. And because the 4 bytes between header and CRC are a count I can see that no messages are dropped (continuous count).

I am confident it is not the CRC check that is wrong when the loading is low.

**EDIT 2:**

Full compilable code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termio.h>
#include <linux/serial.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <time.h>

//The width and depth of the queue, ie the max size message that can be placed on it.
#define C_BUFFER_ENTRY_SIZE 4096
#define C_FIFO_ENTRIES_MAX 10000

typedef struct
{
    char data[C_BUFFER_ENTRY_SIZE];
}ring_buffer_data_t;


typedef struct
{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t fill;
    pthread_cond_t empty;

    int s_icm_idx; // InComing Message index
    int s_ogm_idx; // OutGoing Message index
    int s_entry_count;
    int s_entry_count_hi;
    int used_bytes[C_FIFO_ENTRIES_MAX];
    ring_buffer_data_t buffer[C_FIFO_ENTRIES_MAX];
} ring_buffer_t;


static ring_buffer_t s_rb = {PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER, PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER, 0, 0, 0, 0, {0}, {{{0}}}};
const uint8_t CRC_LUT[256] = {0, 94, 188, 226, 97, 63, 221, 131, 194, 156, 126, 32, 163, 253, 31, 65, 157, 195, 33, 127, 252, 162, 64, 30, 95, 1, 227, 189, 62, 96, 130, 220, 35, 125, 159, 193, 66, 28, 254, 160, 225, 191, 93, 3, 128, 222, 60, 98, 190, 224, 2, 92, 223, 129, 99, 61, 124, 34, 192, 158, 29, 67, 161, 255, 70, 24, 250, 164, 39, 121, 155, 197, 132, 218, 56, 102, 229, 187, 89, 7, 219, 133, 103, 57, 186, 228, 6, 88, 25, 71, 165, 251, 120, 38, 196, 154, 101, 59, 217, 135, 4, 90, 184, 230, 167, 249, 27, 69, 198, 152, 122, 36, 248, 166, 68, 26, 153, 199, 37, 123, 58, 100, 134, 216, 91, 5, 231, 185, 140, 210, 48, 110, 237, 179, 81, 15, 78, 16, 242, 172, 47, 113, 147, 205, 17, 79, 173, 243, 112, 46, 204, 146, 211, 141, 111, 49, 178, 236, 14, 80, 175, 241, 19, 77, 206, 144, 114, 44, 109, 51, 209, 143, 12, 82, 176, 238, 50, 108, 142, 208, 83, 13, 239, 177, 240, 174, 76, 18, 145, 207, 45, 115, 202, 148, 118, 40, 171, 245, 23, 73, 8, 86, 180, 234, 105, 55, 213, 139, 87, 9, 235, 181, 54, 104, 138, 212, 149, 203, 41, 119, 244, 170, 72, 22, 233, 183, 85, 11, 136, 214, 52, 106, 43, 117, 151, 201, 74, 20, 246, 168, 116, 42, 200, 150, 21, 75, 169, 247, 182, 232, 10, 84, 215, 137, 107, 53};
int id;

FILE *log_fh;

void *dequeue_and_log(void* fd)
{
    #define HDR_START 'X'

    // FILE *fd;

    //fd = fopen("log.log", "wb");
    uint8_t parse_buffer[2 * C_BUFFER_ENTRY_SIZE] = {0};
    int bytes_to_write = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(s_rb.mutex));

        while (s_rb.s_entry_count == 0)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&(s_rb.fill), &(s_rb.mutex));
        }
        // Get the incoming data from the buffer
        bytes_to_write = s_rb.used_bytes[s_rb.s_ogm_idx];
        memcpy(parse_buffer, &(s_rb.buffer[s_rb.s_ogm_idx]),bytes_to_write);

        s_rb.s_ogm_idx = (s_rb.s_ogm_idx + 1) % C_FIFO_ENTRIES_MAX;
        s_rb.s_entry_count--;

        pthread_cond_signal(&(s_rb.empty));
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(s_rb.mutex));
        // binary write
        fwrite(parse_buffer,bytes_to_write,1,(FILE*)fd);
    }
}

int add_to_queue(void* a_data, int a_bytes)
{
    int ret_val = 0;

    if (a_bytes > C_BUFFER_ENTRY_SIZE)
    {
        printf("add_to_queue oversized send %i\n", a_bytes);
        return 2;
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&(s_rb.mutex));  

    while (s_rb.s_entry_count == C_FIFO_ENTRIES_MAX) 
    {
        ret_val = 1;
        printf("Queue is FULL\n");
        pthread_cond_wait(&(s_rb.empty), &(s_rb.mutex));
    }

    /* Put the data on the queue, set how many bytes of the queue */
    /* are used and then incoming message index and the queue     */
    /* entry counter.                                             */
    memcpy(&(s_rb.buffer[s_rb.s_icm_idx]), a_data, a_bytes);
    s_rb.used_bytes[s_rb.s_icm_idx] = a_bytes;

    s_rb.s_icm_idx = (s_rb.s_icm_idx + 1) % C_FIFO_ENTRIES_MAX;
    s_rb.s_entry_count++;

    pthread_cond_signal(&(s_rb.fill));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(s_rb.mutex));

    return ret_val;
}

int open_port(char *port_name, int flags, int *fd)
{
    struct termios options;

    //*fd = open(port_name, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    *fd = open(port_name, flags | O_NOCTTY);

    if(*fd < 0){
        printf("Error opening port\n");
        return 1;
    } else{
        printf("Port handle is %d\n", *fd);
    }

    //Assume port has already been setup by receiver
    #if(1)
    options.c_cflag = B3000000 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
    options.c_iflag = 0;
    options.c_oflag = 0;
    options.c_lflag = 0;
    options.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    options.c_cc[VMIN] = 200;
    tcflush(*fd, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(*fd, TCSANOW, &options);
    #endif

    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd;
    int res;
    uint8_t buf[C_BUFFER_ENTRY_SIZE];
    int rc = 0;

    pthread_t p_parse;
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);

    int num_bytes_read = 0;
    int num_buf_byte_remaining = 0;

    #define HB_PRINT_INTERVAL 200

    unsigned long int heartbeat_seq_count = 0;
    unsigned long int heartbeat_seq_count_last_print = 0;

    pthread_mutex_init(&(s_rb.mutex), NULL);

    log_fh = fopen(argv[2], "wb");

    res = open_port(argv[1], O_RDONLY, &fd);
    pthread_create(&p_parse, NULL, dequeue_and_log, (void *)log_fh);

    while(1){
        heartbeat_seq_count++;

        if (heartbeat_seq_count - heartbeat_seq_count_last_print >= HB_PRINT_INTERVAL)
        {
            printf("Sequence ID %10ld\n", heartbeat_seq_count);             
            heartbeat_seq_count_last_print = heartbeat_seq_count;
        }

        num_bytes_read = 0;
        while (num_bytes_read < C_BUFFER_ENTRY_SIZE)
        {
            num_buf_byte_remaining = C_BUFFER_ENTRY_SIZE - num_bytes_read;      
            rc = read(fd, &buf[num_bytes_read], num_buf_byte_remaining);


            if (rc > 0)
            {
                num_bytes_read += rc;
            }
            else if (rc == -1)
            {
                printf("Read error %s\n",strerror(errno));
            }
            else 
            {}
        }

        //add data to logging queue
        add_to_queue(buf, num_bytes_read);
    }

    fclose(log_fh);
    return 0;
}
```

1. Reads from serial adds to queue
2. Second thread reads from queue and writes to disk

A python script post processes the output file to check to see if the data it corrupted. This is run on a separate PC after the test has finished so has no bearing on load. I know this script is fine at parsing data.

There are three things that I have tested and cannot explain

1. VMIN = 200 and no background load = Corrupted data  in the binary file
2. VMIN = 0 and no background load = **NO** Corrupted data in the binary file
3. VMIN = 200 and background load = **NO** Corrupted data in the binary file

Setting VMIN to zero increases the CPU load (as the read loop is running much faster, as the read function is returning 0 quite frequently). Therefore I am unsure if it is actually VMIN causing the issue or more that increasing the CPU load makes the read behave normally.

To retiterate, it is not the decode function. That function works perfectly from the file in the no corrupted data cases above.

Comment: What errors are you getting? As for (2) I would make the read blocking instead. You are blocking it yourself anyway until the full buffer is read, then why not let `read` to take care of that in a proper way?

Comment: Error detection code not posted so unnecessarily difficult to see why errors occur more or less.  Post a [mcve]

Comment: @Eugene - Are those settings not already blocking?

Comment: @chux - It is not important for this. Every packet is 7 bytes long. First byte is a header character, 4 bytes of a count, followed by a CRC 16 check.  The issue is not related.

Comment: @Lhh92 Right, it is blocking. Still, you are talking about errors, but the only error handling we see here is for `rc == -1` and appears that you are not talking about these - which is misleading. Please provide more information about the errors. Everything is related.

Comment: Serial ports do not have packets - it is a byte at a time.  Header character is indistinguishable from CRC bytes.  Receiving system can easily get out of phase.  Seeing how code syncs on incoming data (or lack of good syncing) is important and can easily explain the issue.

Comment: Try setting VTIME > 0 as explained here http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/termios-vmin-vtime.html. This makes read() not teturn immediately if nothing was received.

Comment: What is `fd`? Sometimes you use it dereferenced, `*fd = open(..)` and `tcsetattr(*fd,...)`, but you also use the pointer value, `read(fd, ...)`.  Your termios initialization is problematic.  See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237)

Comment: Your **read()** request can cause undefined behavior. (1) A pointer (?) to the file descriptor is the argument instead of the file descriptor.  (2) A minimum of 200 bytes is specified by VMIN, but as `buf` is filled by each read request, eventually `num_buf_byte_remaining` could be less than VMIN.  That's an illogical request.  Also set VTIME > 0 as @ulix suggested (but for the wrong reason).

Comment: @sawdust, based on doc link i posted, paragraph "VMIN > 0 and VTIME > 0 " please ecplain what's the "wrong reason"  ?

Comment: @ulix -- The existing VTIME=0 and VMIN=200  already *"makes read() not teturn immediately"*.

Comment: @sawdust - apologies I had incorrectly copied the code over. The terminos struct is set up in a function called open_port. I have made the above changes.

Comment: High load may change the timing. Maybe in one case the consumer has already processed all data before new data arrive from the producer and in the other case the consumer has to append new data to partially processed data. You should also show the code that consumes the data from the ring buffer. How do you handle communication frames that are split between the end of one buffer and the start of the next buffer. How can you distinguish a header byte from other bytes? A CRC byte can have the same value as your header byte. How do you find the next header byte when you detect a CRC error?

Comment: I have added the code. You can see it just logs to file - you are correct about the timing, I think there is something in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code doesn't work in a common condition that you can't prevent from happening, the why of "Why [it] only work[s] with high CPU?" doesn't really matter.  It's probably interesting to spend a lot of time and effort finding out the "Why?", but I'd think you're going to have to change your code because anything that stops working when CPU load goes down is, IMO, waaaaay too fragile to trust to work for any time.

First, is threading even useful on your system?  If there's only one CPU that can run only one thread at a time, creating multiple threads will be counterproductive.  Have you tried a simple single-threaded solution and actually found that it doesn't work?

If you have tried a single-threaded solution and it doesn't work, the first thing I note is that your currently posted code is doing a tremendous amount of extra work it doesn't need to do, and it's likely contending over a single lock when that doesn't help much at all.

So eliminate your extraneous copying of data along with all the unnecessary bookkeeping you're doing.

You also probably have a lot of contention with just a single mutex and condition variable. There's no need to not read because the logging thread is doing something, or the logging thread not processing because the read thread is doing some bookkeeping. You'd almost certainly benefit from finer lock granularity.

I'd do something like this:

```
#define CHUNK_SIZE ( 4 * 1024 )
#define NUM_BUFFERS 16

struct dataStruct
{
    sem_t full;
    sem_t empty;
    ssize_t count;
    char data[ CHUNK_SIZE ]
};

struct dataStruct dataArray[ NUM_BUFFERS ];

void initDataArray( void )
{
    for ( int ii = 0; ii < NUM_BUFFERS; ii++ )
    {
        // buffers all start empty
        sem_init( &( dataArray[ ii ].full ), 0, 0 );
        sem_init( &( dataArray[ ii ].empty ), 0, 1 );
    }
}

void *readPortThread( void *arg )
{
    unsigned currBuffer = 0;

    // get portFD from arg
    int portFD = ???
    for ( ;; )
    {
        sem_wait( &( dataArray[ currBuffer  ].empty ) );

        // probably should loop and read more, and don't
        // infinite loop on any error (hint...)
        dataArray[ currBuffer  ].count = read( portFD, 
            dataArray[ currBuffer  ].data,
            sizeof( dataArray[ currBuffer  ].data ) );
        sem_post( &( dataArray[ currBuffer  ].full ) );
        currBuffer++;
        currBuffer  %= NUM_BUFFERS;
    }
    return( NULL );
}

void *processData( char *data, ssize_t count )
{
    ...
}

void *logDataThread( void *arg )
{
    for ( ;; )
    {
        sem_wait( &( dataArray[ currBuffer  ].full ) );

        processData( dataArray[ currBuffer  ].data,
            dataArray[ currBuffer  ].count );

        sem_post( &( dataArray[ currBuffer  ].empty ) );
        currBuffer++;
        currBuffer  %= NUM_BUFFERS;
    }
    return( NULL );
}
```

Note the much finer locking granularity, and the complete lack of extraneous copying of data.  Proper headers, all error checking, and full implementation are left as an exercise...

You'll have to test to find optimum values for `CHUNK_SIZE` and `NUM_BUFFERS`.  Setting the number of buffers dynamically would be a good improvement also.

OT: There's no need for any indirection in your `int open_port(int flags, int *fd)` function.  Simply return the `fd` value - it's good enough for `open()` itself:

```
int open_port(int flags )
{
    struct termios options;
    int fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", flags | O_NOCTTY);

    if(fd < 0){
        printf("Error opening port\n");
        return fd;
    }

    // no need for else - the above if statement returns
    printf("Port handle is %d\n", fd);

    // did you set **ALL** the fields???
    memset( options, 0, sizeof( options ) );

    options.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
    options.c_iflag = 0;
    options.c_oflag = 0;
    options.c_lflag = 0;
    options.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    options.c_cc[VMIN] = 200;
    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);

    return fd;
}
```